# Getting Duration

Tags: c, time

I'm trying to measure duration of something.
when it start I call start_time = time(NULL);
when it ends:

```
time_t a_time = time(NULL) - start_time;
struct tm * ts = localtime(&a_time);
char time_buff[32];
memset (time_buff,0,32);
sprintf (time_buff, "Duration: %02d:%02d:%02d", ts->tm_hour, ts->tm_min, ts->tm_sec);
```

The problem is that ts->tm_hour is always 2.

Please advise.
Thanks,
Nahum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you eventualy live in a country where the time is 2 hours away from UTC time ?

replace your call to `localtime()` (which is in your current timezone) by a call to  `gmtime()`.

Answer (score 2):

The function `localtime` converts the time to a complete date and time. You better convert it to days, hours and minutes yourself though divisions and modulo operations.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a function that returns the amount of milliseconds elapsed (clock or gettimeofday) and then convert to hour/min/sec?